# Azure alert - unable to find previously created and deleted alert

Tags: azure, alert

A while ago, I created an alert to monitor for any Azure pipelines that have failed.

The alert has since been deleted, and no longer shows in the "Alerts & Metrics" page.

However I am still receiving email notification from this alert, when the alert detected a job failure.

What I need is to find this alert, and DELETE it from running again.

Does someone have any insights on how to find this mysterious alert that no longer show up ?

Clicking on the link from the email notification returns "Not Found".

I am looking for the alert in the "Alert & Metrics" Page: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDulp.png)

Answer (score 0):

please check the `Manage alert rules` and `manage action groups`, maybe you can find the alert.

> `Azure Dashboard ⇒ Serach services ⇒ Monitor ⇒ Alerts ⇒ Manage alert rules, Manage action groups`.

Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately the alert is not listed in the above location(Azure Dashboard ⇒ Serach services ⇒ Monitor ⇒ Alerts ⇒ Manage alert rules, Manage action groups.) .  I see other ones that I created from before, but just not the one that I am looking for.

Comment: Have you set the right 'Subscription, Resource group, Resource type, Resource, Singal type, Status', please have a check. @ken.

Comment: I'm in the same boat here. I deleted an alert and it's continuous firing. Cannot find it on thie Monitor | Alerts screen no matter what I set the filters to. Previously had to delete the AI instance completely to solve this. Pretty frustrating.